# What happens at the receive part when we write with SPI?

Tags: embedded, spi, serial-communication

When SPI master writes to the slave, something is shifting into the receive buffer right? 
If yes, then it is normal "RXDATAAVAILABLE" flag to be set? It is nonsense! We send data, and when data is sent, we get notified that there is data received.

If all of my statements are correct, then how do we know what the correct data is into the RXFIFO?

Suppose we send two bytes frame. The first one is the address and the second one is dummy in order to read the value in that address (of the slave). Then suppose we have two levels Rx FIFO. In that FIFO instead the value read from the slave, we have two bytes, the first is who knows what, and the second the value read from the slave.

So the question is: how do we manage to receive only what is necessary, without getting junk data during the write part of the frame?

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/serial-peripheral-interface-spi
This should allow you to better understand SPI - I've a feeling this question is too general and you have not supplied working examples.

Comment: This is definitely not a "C" question. You might ask that question in http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ or follow the recommendation above.

Comment: SPI is a very simplistic interface, designed to get devices on the same printed circuit board to talk to each other.  Implicit with the way they are designed, if there is "crap" then that problem started between the chair and the keyboard or the next cubicle.

Comment: you are clearly talking about a specific spi controller, they come in as many shapes and sizes as clothes or cars.   One does not have to design a controller that way, but it is far simpler to just have two shifters one in and one out, tell it to shift N bits and let the software sort it out from the shifted in data.  Could complicate it more and only shift in when the slave is expected to be driving.  You could also just bit bang it and then you only look at miso when you expect something there.

Comment: you can shop around before you buy a microcontroller or spi master device and find one that does what you want rather than use the one you have.  you can also bit bang one or you can get a cpld or fpga and build a master that does exactly what you want.

Comment: SPI is only a physical layer - you have to implement higher level protocols to handle the problems you mention.  It works most efficiently with duplex streaming data (simultaneous read and write).  To do a read-only or write-only operation you necessarily have to send dummy data or discard junk data.  It is not nonsense - SPI is a very simple hardware implementation that takes minimal die space; for that hardware efficiency you have to accept greater software overhead compared to other communications interfaces such as I2C, USART, Ethernet or USB (in order of complexity and die space).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is pure hardware question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SPI works like simple 8 bit shift registers. You shift out bytes on MOSI at each flank of a clock and at the same time you shift in new data from MISO. Thus you send and receive at the same time. Hence the names MOSI = Master Out Slave In, and MISO = Master In Slave Out.

SPI peripherals on microcontrollers are more intricate than that though, and have separate data registers that are different from the actual hardware shift register, so that we can write data without worrying about the pending transmission. Some may even have multiple data buffers. But on the fundamental level, SPI always work with 8 bits.

When the microcontroller acting as SPI master writes something, there is usually two flags, one that says that the data buffer is made available, and another that tells that transmission is done.

When you are done sending, you are also done receiving. You'll get some sort of flag set. This is assuming that all devices are implementing SPI as intended, which is often not the case.

Note that some devices implement a system where you first send x bytes of data, and after that receive x bytes of data. This seems to be the scenario you describe. Sending and receiving is not done at the same time for that device, but instead in sequence. Meaning that during the first transmission, you'll clock in garbage, and then in order to receive data, you must clock out garbage. This is no fault of SPI, but how the manufacturer of the specific device has specified things.

Note that SPI is very poorly standardized and therefore all manner of weird crap exists on the market. The manner of sending/receiving data may vary, the clock polarity (flanks) may vary, where the device clocks the data may vary. Some devices might need delays between data bytes. Some devices might need some obscure handling of the Slave Select pin in order to work. It's all one big mess and the lack of international standardization is to blame.

Comment: This is a hardware question and not related to software. It should be closed and not answered.

Comment: @Olaf SPI is pretty much 50/50 hardware/software. I don't see how it would be off-topic. You gonna run around closing all the questions about RS-232 and Windows com ports too?

Comment: If they ask about how RS232 works (voltage levels, etc.), sure. And I disagree SPI is 50% software. You can implement an SPI slave with e.g. simple 74HC594, a master with 1-2 more standard logic ICs and have both interworking without a CPU. At least one side being simple hardware was actually the idea behind SPI. So no, it is not suitable at stack overflow. But the question could be suitable at electronics.

Comment: @Olaf Similarly, you can implement SPI as 100% pure software with bit-banging.

Comment: How do you transfer data? Telekinesis? ;-) Sorry, I very well have weighted  if the question is within the rules as I understand them. I don't think so. With a different focus and actual code, it might be different. But OP is clearly after the basics. You wouldn't accept a question how PICe works either. As I already mentioned, it might be fine for electronics, though. Let's just agree to disagree, ok?

Comment: @Olaf - the *problem* here is a software one.  The hardware is operating as designed.  The problem is that the software (/programmer) is not ignoring meaningless data as it/they should.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: WIthout having the hardware in my lab, a scope attached and the hardware proven to work, I generally don't make **any** assumptions. That saved me weeks of debugging session already.

Comment: No assumptions are necessary.  One only needs to *actually read the question* to understand that it is independent of any particular hardware.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: The start is wrong already. Whether there is a RXRDY/RXNE/etc. or just some "BUSY" flag depends on the hardware implementation. Same for a RXFIFO. Most implementations **at most** are double-buffered, some not even that.

Answer (score 1):

An SPI master engine's received data available flag will be set as a simple result of the occurrence of a word's worth of clock cycles generated by the master itself.  It tells you nothing about the operation or even existence of a peripheral on the bus.

When this flag is set, it is entirely up to you and your software to know if the contents of the received data register will have meaning or not.

- If you have properly selected and interacted with an existent, operational peripheral in a *read* or *transfer* operation where it is documented to give a result, they will have meaning
- If you have performed a purely *write* operation to a peripheral for which no reply data is documented at the word position in question, it will be meaningless, effectively no different than reading some random legal memory location.  Note that in most cases, a write operation is simply a transfer where the received data is to be ignored - at implementation level there is usually no other difference.
- If you have failed to address any existent peripheral it will be similarly be meaningless.

As with any other memory or read operation, it is up to you to know if the contents of the register in a particular situation are meaningful or not.

**Since you know that the first byte contains "who knows what" while the second has meaning, write your software to ignore the first and use the second.**

(As an aside, many, though by no means all, SPI peripherals are documented to shift out whatever constitutes their primary status register during the address phase, since that makes for a quick way to poll it)

Comment: There is something else. I intend to use DMA for the reception. This means that I need to prepare four bytes for upcoming frame when I need only two. This is due to the specific work of the DMA. I simply can not tell the DMA ignore the first two bytes and take the second two. I want to liberate the CPU from this transfer. Yes I can prepare four bytes transfer and only take the last two. It some kind of annoy me because I need to alocate four bytes :-). Anyway Thank you @Chris Stratton.

Comment: Indeed, if you are going to use DMA you will indeed probably need to prepare buffers of the full transfer size, and ignore the part of the buffer you do not use.  That's just how SPI works.